IF cell is BLANK then VLOOKUP multiple criteria
I need help with excel formula. Can someone help me to solve this formula as it show FALSE for the blank cell
=IFERROR(IF(C12="Route Stage",VLOOKUP(D12,'Route Stages'!A:B,2,0),
         IF(C12="Item",VLOOKUP(D12,'Item list'!A:B,2,0),
         IF(C12="Resource",VLOOKUP(D12,Resource!A:B,2,0),
         IF(C12="Art No",VLOOKUP(D12,'Item list'!A:B,2,0))))),"")



Try wrapping with an IF() function before performing all the Nested IFs() with VLOOKUP() functions:
=IF(C12="","",
 IFERROR(IF(C12="Route Stage",VLOOKUP(D12,'Route Stages'!A:B,2,0),
         IF(C12="Item",VLOOKUP(D12,'Item list'!A:B,2,0),
         IF(C12="Resource",VLOOKUP(D12,Resource!A:B,2,0),
         IF(C12="Art No",VLOOKUP(D12,'Item list'!A:B,2,0))))),
 ""))


Also, I will suggest you, to convert the source ranges into Structured References aka Tables and use the following formula provided the Lookup_Values are always unique across the sheets:
=IF(C12="","",VLOOKUP(D12,VSTACK(Item_List,Route_Stages,Resources),2,0))


Where:

Item_List is the Structured References of the source data in sheet Item List
Route_Stages is the Structured References of the source data in sheet Route Stages
Resources is the Structured References of the source data in sheet Resources



Thanks Mayuks... It works..
